# Finding Probability function

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I have trouble in a particular kind of questions and that's when I am asked to find the probability function. I do not know how to approach these questions.I need help with how to address this line of questions.

A question and answer for those question is posted below.

Two balls are drawn at random from a box containing 10 balls numbered 0-9. Let the random variable X ~ Maximum of two number drawn

a)If sampling is done without replacement, determine the probability 
    function of X?

b) If sampling is done with replacement, determine the probability 
    function of X?

Answer for A $$ f_x(x) = \frac {2x}{10^{(2)}} $$

Answer for B $$ f_x(x) = \frac {2x + 1}{10^{2}} $$

Comment: The way to adress this type of questions is usually to find some specific cases (for example $f_{X}(0)$, $f_{X}(1)$, $f_{X}(2)$ and to try to figure out what the general rule looks like. See if you can find a pattern.

For example. $f_{X}(0) = 0$ clearly in the first case, because only one of the balls you draw can be null. On the other hand, in the second case, $f_{X}(0) \neq 0$ because the $0$ ball is replaced after you draw it, so you could draw it again.

Comment: How did you obtain these answers?  Please edit your question to show your attempt.

Comment: Those answers was at the back of the book no explanation was provided. I will edit and add my attempt.